# Drupal 7 Views and Rules Action Sets

Tags: drupal-7, vbo, drupal-rules

I have created a view based on profile fields to display a custom search page for a particular role.
Once the search results are displayed, the user can select one of them to send a notification.

For this a VBO has been used with a force single option. I have problems when i try to send an email notification thru rules, to the selected user.

I do not see the custom rules action to send email, under my bulk operation settings.
If i try to create the rule component with data type profile, i get the action listed under bulk operations, but not on my page.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved by enabling permissions for that particular user role to execute the Rule. By default, the Rule was enabled only for the creator (Admin).